# Custom bootstrap pagination style does not work

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a typescript react project with react-paginate package for pagination. Though I tried different specifities, I can't still change the default style. Those custom styles seems not applied even if I try using id match! Any help would be much appreciated.

My css looks like: (index.css):

```
.ul.pagination > li > a
{
    background-color: white;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}

.ul.pagination > li > a:focus,
.ul.pagination > li > a:hover,
.ul.pagination > li > span:focus,
.ul.pagination > li > span:hover
{
    color: #075cfb;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-color: #4d71f2;
}

.pagination > .active > a
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #2d2b2f !Important;
    border: solid 1px #5c5b5d !Important;
}

.pagination > .active > a:hover
{
    background-color: #5A4181 !Important;
    border: solid 1px #5A4181;
}
```

and my page where I have used react-paginate package:

```
     <div
        id="paginator"
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <ReactPaginate
          breakLabel="..."
          nextLabel=">>"
          onPageChange={handlePageClick}
          pageRangeDisplayed={2}
          pageCount={pagination?.totalPages || 0}
          previousLabel="<<"
          renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
          breakClassName="page-item"
          breakLinkClassName="page-link"
          containerClassName="pagination justify-content-center"
          pageClassName="page-item"
          pageLinkClassName="page-link"
          previousClassName="page-item"
          previousLinkClassName="page-link"
          nextClassName="page-item"
          nextLinkClassName="page-link"
          activeClassName="active"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with incorrect reference to CSS file path and once I got fixed, it works fine.